# SQL Server 2008 get last row by unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with the name `Events`. I want to get only every last entry from `RadioNumber`.

My SQL is the following:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(timestamp) AS TimeStamp,
    RadioNumber,
    info,
    RadioNumberInfo,
    success
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
     FROM Events
     WHERE Type = 1
       AND (Info IN (SELECT '1 Frei Funk' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '2 Frei Wache' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '3 Ausgerückt' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '5 Sprechwunsch' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '7 Patient aufg' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '8 Am Transportziel' FROM Events))) AS tmp
GROUP BY 
    tmp.RadioNumber, tmp.Info, tmp.RadioNumberInfo, tmp.Success
ORDER BY 
    Timestamp DESC
```

The result looks like this and the red framed rows are the rows which I want to display.

[image]

What I have to change, to show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your input and help. I found with a little help by using join.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Events AS a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(a.ID) AS ID, MAX(a.TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp, a.RadioNumber 
    FROM Events AS a 
    WHERE a.Type = 1 
    AND a.Info IN ('1 Frei Funk','2 Frei Wache','3 Ausgerückt','5 Sprechwunsch','7 Patient aufg','8 Am Transportziel') 
GROUP BY a.RadioNumber
) AS b ON b.ID = a.ID 
ORDER BY b.TimeStamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by tmp.RadioNumber order by Max(timestamp));
```

Comment: I don't get it. can you please be more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT
q.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      MAX(timestamp) AS TimeStamp
    , RadioNumber
    , info
    , RadioNumberInfo
    , success
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RadioNumber ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) RN
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
        FROM Events
        WHERE Type = 1
        AND (Info IN (SELECT '1 Frei Funk' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '2 Frei Wache' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '3 Ausgerückt' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '5 Sprechwunsch' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '7 Patient aufg' FROM Events)
            OR Info IN (SELECT '8 Am Transportziel' FROM Events))
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY tmp.RadioNumber, tmp.Info, tmp.RadioNumberInfo, tmp.Success
 )q
 WHERE q.RN = 1
```

And an example with similar data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    FooStamp DATETIME,
    RadioNumber INT,
    Info VARCHAR(50),
    Success tinyint
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    FooStamp,
    RadioNumber,
    Info,
    Success
)
VALUES
(
    '2019-03-10 00:27:30', -- FooStamp - DATETIME
    1, -- RadioNumber - INT
    'Info 1', -- Info - VARCHAR
    1 -- Success - tinyint
)
, ('2019-03-10 00:27:31', 1, 'Info 1', 1)
, ('2019-03-10 00:27:32', 1, 'Info 1', 1)
, ('2019-03-10 00:27:33', 1, 'Info 2', 1)
, ('2019-03-10 00:28:38', 2, 'Info 2', 1)
, ('2019-03-10 00:29:38', 3, 'Info 3', 1)
```

and query:

```
SELECT 
q.*
FROM
(
SELECT 
  MAX(t.FooStamp) MaxFooStamp
, t.RadioNumber 
, t.Info
, t.Success
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.RadioNumber ORDER BY MAX(t.FooStamp)) RN
FROM @table t
GROUP BY   t.RadioNumber
         , t.Info
         , t.Success
)q
WHERE q.RN = 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
MaxFooStamp                 RadioNumber    Info   Success   RN
2019-10-03 00:27:32.000          1         Info1     1       1
2019-10-03 00:28:38.000          2         Info2     1       1
2019-10-03 00:29:38.000          3         Info3     1       1
```

Comment: thanks a lot! your example works at the first look :)
I am not good in SQL and if I run your query I dont get the latest results from each `RadioNumber`.
After some trial and error on your example without success I can't explain it by myself what is wrong.

Comment: @wuk986 1. Your sample data and desired output will clarify  what you want to do and eliminate the errors. 2. If you query gives the output you've shown here, then my reply should work and compile without error. 3. Try to see an example which is posted in  the reply and see how `ROW_NUMBER()` is used

Answer (score 0):

you can use correlated subquery

```
SELECT timestamp AS TimeStamp,
       RadioNumber,
       info,
       RadioNumberInfo,
       success
FROM   (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
        FROM   Events
        WHERE  Type = 1
               AND ( Info IN (SELECT '1 Frei Funk'
                              FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '2 Frei Wache'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '3 Ausgerückt'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '5 Sprechwunsch'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '7 Patient aufg'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '8 Am Transportziel'
                                  FROM   Events) )) AS tmp
where timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from 
FROM   Events
        WHERE  Type = 1
               AND ( Info IN (SELECT '1 Frei Funk'
                              FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '2 Frei Wache'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '3 Ausgerückt'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '5 Sprechwunsch'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '7 Patient aufg'
                                  FROM   Events)
                      OR Info IN (SELECT '8 Am Transportziel'
                                  FROM   Events) )) tmp1 where radionumber=tmp1.radionumber)
```